# Searching for Extensionless Files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search, file-extension, file-search

I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to have Windows 7 Explorer search for files with no extension. In XP it was nice and simple: just search for files named `*.` but in 7, that does not work and returns *all* files, as does `ext:.`.

Searching has become extremely burdensome in Windows 7. Does anyone know how to perform this previously simple task?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to MSDN, the nothing character is `[]`.  So press <kbd>F3</kbd> and enter `ext:[]`.

Comment: That kind of, almost works. It returns file that indeed have no extension, but it also returns some files that are labeled as having no extension even though they contain one or more periods, as well as *all* folders, even ones that contain periods. Hmm, it looks like Windows 7 cannot even tell the type of files and/or correctly parse filenames/extension. (I like Win7 less and less every day.)

Comment: Strange, files with multiple periods by definition have an extension and those files don't show up on my system. Folders have extensions also, so that isn't just for files. If you want *just files* you should add a filter:`NOT kind:folder` since it implicitly searches all object types, not just files. I can't help you with the Win 7  like/dislike.

Answer (score 4):

As @surfasb points out the [] can be used to represent 'nothing', and you can use it with the `ext:` filter.

You can then use that in combination with the `type:` filter and tell it to NOT show file folders:

`ext:[] type:NOT"file folder"`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue today on Windows 8 and have noticed it on previously on Windows 7 as well. I finally found a way to do this right and I hope this answer helps the original posters and others who come here via google searches.

Typically for normal as well as advanced power searches I used [Nirsoft SearchMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html) and stopped using Windows Search.

[image]

But, for some reason I was having trouble getting it to find files without any extensions. I figured the same bug was there in this app as well.

But, I was wrong and apparently Nir Softer has redesigned his wild card & regular expression engine from scratch; as per this little gem I found posted on the page in "Versions History" section:

> - Version 2.40:
>
>   - SearchMyFiles now uses an internal wildcard parser instead of basing the search result on the wildcard parser of Windows. This
>       change solves an annoying bug caused by Windows wildcard parser: In
>       previous versions, SearchMyFiles sometimes returned incorrect results,
>       because Windows also matches the wildcard with the short filename (8.3
>       DOS format).
>   - Notice: The new wildcard parser may cause some compatibility issues, for example: When you scanned using *.* wildcard with Windows
>       parser, it returned all files, including files without extension. With
>       the new SearchMyFiles wildcard parser, *.* returns only files with
>       extension. In order to return all files, you should use * instead of
>       *.*
>   - When loading old config files, SearchMyFiles automatically converts all *.* wildcards to *
>   - The new wildcard parser has some advantages, for example: if you search for *.*.*.*, you'll get all files with 3 dot characters or
>       more. With Windows wildcard parser in previous versions, you simply
>       got the list of all files.
>   - You can now exclude files by using wildcards list. You have to select this option from the combo-box, because the default option is
>       to exclude files by extension.
>   - You can now specify environment strings in the 'Base Folders' and 'Excluded Folders' fields (For example: %AppData% )

So to find files without extensions don't use these:

```
*.* or *.
```

Just use a simple:

```
*
```

For example :

> ```
> Files Wildcard: *
> Subfolders Wildcard: *
> ```

Note: Please don't go by the wild cards shown in the 'old' screenshot posted above.